# Missing categorical annotations in R pheatmap() despite no missing values in data

Tags: r, annotations, heatmap, pheatmap

I am trying to make a clustere emphasized text*d heatmap with pheatmap() in R for cytokine values. I also want to add in annotations based on a categorical variable with 4 different options. Despite ensuring there is no missing data the annotations have multiple rows with no colored annotation. As seen in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3sTi.png)

My original data set had 380 samples, but I cleaned the data to only include rows that have no missing values, which brought me down to 154 samples with 41 variables. Here are the names of the variables-

```
[1] "tbm_category" "tnfa"         "il6"          "il33"         "il3"          "il8"          "il7"          "ip10"         "il10"  
[10] "egf"          "vegf"         "grob"         "il1b"         "ifng"         "il1ra"        "mip3a"        "il12"         "mip1a"  
[19] "il31"         "mip1b"        "il1a"         "il4"          "mip3b"        "il2"          "groa"         "fractalkine"  "fgfbasic"  
[28] "eotaxin"      "il15"         "il5"          "gcsf"         "pdgfaa"       "mcp1"         "ifna"         "il21"         "trail"  
[37] "tnfsf5"       "il23"         "flt3ligand"   "il18"         "granzymeb"`
```

The "tbm_category" is a categorical variable with 4 different groups and these are the options and their counts:

| Definite TBM | Not TBM |
| --- | --- |
| 26 | 57 |

| Possible TBM | Probable TBM |
| --- | --- |
| 52 | 19 |

The data is called "cleaned_cyto_ordered" and I ordered it based on "tbm_category".

I also grouped the cytokines together for ease of coding:
`numeric_variables <- names(cleaned_cyto_ordered)[names(cleaned_cyto_ordered) != "tbm_category"]`

Here is my check to ensure no missing values

```
if (any_missing) {print("There are missing values in the dataset.")} else {print("There are no missing values in the dataset.")}
[1] "There are no missing values in the dataset."
```

My goal is to cluster the cytokine data and then add the colored annotations based on tbm_category. The code I used to create the heat map I attached (I log10 transformed the cytokine values as they tend to be extremely small and to get any meaningful analysis you have to lag10 transform):

```
pheatmap(log10(cleaned_cyto_ordered[, numeric_variables]),
         annotation_row = data.frame(Category= cleaned_cyto_ordered$tbm_category),
         scale = "row",
         cluster_rows = FALSE,
         show_rownames = FALSE, clustering_distance_cols = "correlation")
```

## **I have been playing around with this all day and I have given up hope to fixingt the missing categorical annotations. Any help is greatly appreciated**